How can I create an in-memory file object that has a file descriptor in Python?
I plan to use subprocess.Popen (in Python 3.11.2) to implement git mktree < foo.txt. Now I face the question.
In order to reproduce my situation, here is the script that creates the environment.
#!/bin/bash

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=foo
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=foo@bar.com
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Tue Jun 4 21:40:15 2024 +0800"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=foo
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=foo@bar.com
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Tue Jun 4 21:40:15 2024 +0800"

rm -rf foo
git init foo
mkdir -p foo/hello
echo hello > foo/hello/hello.txt
echo hello > foo/hello.txt
echo world > foo/world.txt
git -C foo add .
git -C foo commit -m 'hello world'
git -C foo log --no-decorate
git -C foo ls-tree HEAD hello.txt
git -C foo ls-tree HEAD world.txt

It's expected to print the commit and 2 blob entries.
commit d2b25fd15c1435f515dd6379eca8d691dde6abeb
Author: foo <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 4 21:40:15 2024 +0800

    hello world
100644 blob ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a    hello.txt
100644 blob cc628ccd10742baea8241c5924df992b5c019f71    world.txt

I want to create a commit from the tree that has only hello.txt and world.txt. So first I need to create the new tree object. (Update: after getting the right solution, I find that the code has a fatal bug. It creates a tree object with wrong content due to str and bytes.)
import subprocess

# get the blob entry of hello.txt
o, e = subprocess.Popen(
    ['git', 'ls-tree', 'HEAD', 'hello.txt'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
).communicate()
line1 = o.decode()

# get the blob entry of world.txt
o, e = subprocess.Popen(
    ['git', 'ls-tree', 'HEAD', 'world.txt'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
).communicate()
line2 = o.decode()

# write the 2 lines to foo.txt
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(line1)
    f.write(line2)

# create a new tree object from foo.txt
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    o, e = subprocess.Popen(
        ['git', 'mktree'],
        stdin=f,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
    ).communicate()
    tree = o.decode()
    print(f'created tree object {tree}')

I wonder if I can use an in-memory file object so that I don't have to create and remove foo.txt. As io.StringIO is recommended in many answers, I try the code.
import subprocess
import io

line1 = '100644 blob ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a\thello.txt\n'
line2 = '100644 blob cc628ccd10742baea8241c5924df992b5c019f71\tworld.txt\n'

with io.StringIO(line1 + line2) as f:
    o, e = subprocess.Popen(
        ['git', 'mktree'],
        stdin=f,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
    ).communicate()
    tree = o.decode()
    print(f'created tree object {tree}')

It raises an exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 892, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1339, in _get_handles
    p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin.fileno())
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

According to the io doc, it seems io.StringIO does not have a file descriptor.

fileno()
Return the underlying file descriptor (an integer) of the
stream if it exists. An OSError is raised if the IO object does not
use a file descriptor.

Is there any in-memory file object that has a file descriptor? Or is there any method to bypass the exception with io.StringIO in subprocess.Popen?
Update:
With the help of @Ture Pålsson 's answer, I get the expected solution.
import subprocess

# get the blob entry of hello.txt
line1, _ = subprocess.Popen(
    ['git', 'ls-tree', 'HEAD', 'hello.txt'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
).communicate()

# get the blob entry of world.txt
line2, _ = subprocess.Popen(
    ['git', 'ls-tree', 'HEAD', 'world.txt'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
).communicate()

# create a tree object from the lines
# although Popen's text=True allows communicate's input to be str,
# here it should be bytes.
# str input creates a tree object with wrong content.
o, e = subprocess.Popen(
    ['git', 'mktree'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    env={'GIT_DIR': 'foo/.git'},
).communicate(input=line1+line2)


tree = o.decode().strip()
print(f'created tree object {tree}')


Try parentheses around the StringIO call thus: with (io.StringIO(line1 + line2)) as f:

@OldBoy I tried adding parentheses and it raised the same exception. Could you please explain the difference between with and without parentheses? Thanks.

If you’re planning to do anything reasonably heavyweight I’d recommend libgit2 (e.g. via pygit2). That will be easier to script and probably significantly faster too.

I guess I misread something yesterday, it seems to work with or without. Which leads me to believe that the error is nothing to do with StreamIO.

subprocess.run ships out of the box with pretty much all of what you are doing manually here. There's really no need to use subprocess.Popen these days unless you want a concurrently running process.

@nneonneo Thanks for the advice. I once learned about pygit2 and found it was like a hammer on a gnat. My tasks are simple and I'm familiar with git commands, so I usually use GitPython. Its ability to translate and call git commands directly is suitable for me. However, this ability can't handle with the case where stdin is involved.

@MisterMiyagi Thanks. I'll learn about subprocess.run.

Unless I am missing something, you can set stdin=PIPE when building the Popen object, and pass the input as the argument to communicate.
Here’s what I used as a "smoke test":
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(['cat'],
                      encoding='utf-8',
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    o, e = p.communicate('foo')
print(o, e)


Thanks for the answer. Could you please give a demo?

I searched and found this answer. Now I understand what your answer means. Thanks again!
